# use table and join tables if variable

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Lets say I have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, 
     c.c_date 
FROM table_a a 
    JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.id  
WHERE c_date is null;
```

I then also have this variable: **p_filter**

When this variable is equal to 'yes' I want the query shown previously to execute as shown so that table a and table c join and that c_date is searched for null values. If the variable is equal to 'no' or to any other value I would like to not use table_c and to not join so that the query would then execute such as this:

```
    SELECT a.id 
    --omitted c.c_date 
FROM table_a a ;
    --omitted JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.id  
   --omitted  WHERE c_date is null;
```

Comment: Please tag the correct rdbms.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Done. It is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your can try this;)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 
     CASE WHEN $p_filter = 'yes' THEN c.c_date ELSE NULL END AS c_date
FROM table_a a 
JOIN table_c c ON $p_filter = 'no' OR (a.id = c.id AND c.c_date IS NULL);
```

**Edited:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 
     c.c_date
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_c c ON $p_filter = 'yes' AND a.id = c.id AND c.c_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: won't this still include table_c when p_filter = 'N'? When I run it and it is equal to N I am getting redundant rows.

Comment: @user2924127 You're right, it'll give you duplicated result. Updated answer, check it again please. `LEFT JOIN` answer should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

u can use union

```
SELECT a.id, c.c_date
  FROM table_a a JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.id
 WHERE :p_filter = 'yes' AND c_date IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT a.id, NULL c_date
  FROM table_a a
 WHERE NVL (:p_filter, 'no') != 'yes'
```